# Reading ISR status in MATLAB/ SIMULINK

Tags: matlab, interrupt, simulink

I want to read the status of interrupts on my PC through a MATLAB script or SIMULINK block.

Req:
    Need to know the status of COM1 interrupt (IRQ4), so that i can use that as a Trigger in my Simulink model.

If there is an easier workaround, it is welcome too.

Comment: Er, read the ISR in a [C/C++](http://www.drdobbs.com/implementing-interrupt-service-routines/184401485) function, and access it with [MEX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html)?

Comment: There's a pretty comprehensive answer to this question [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97373-is-it-possible-to-read-from-or-write-to-a-serial-port-with-matlab).  It deals with MATLAB, but the suggestions extend simply to Simulink.